Should the creator of a Google Workspace be able to disable an Organisation Level constraint in WCP?
I have created a Google Workspace for our small not-for-profit organisation, and have the Admin account. I am now trying to set up Synology backups.
Using the same account in GCP, I have set up a Project and am trying to create a Service Key. However, the disableServiceAccountKeyCreation constraint is set. I can view the constraint, and can see that it is Enforced. However the Edit option is not available to me, and I get a pop up saying that I need additional permissions. I am the Organisation Administrator.
How do I prevent the Enforcement of this constraint, at least while I generate a Service Key?
